# What is the history of the noun 'false banana'?

Tags: etymology

What is the earliest usage of the noun 'false banana'?

The earliest use of the noun 'false banana' I can find is on 1837, but I expected it to be around 1700.

Also, I would like to know what the history of the noun is (who first used it, how the noun spread, etc)

Comment: [Related](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTTrXAE7OPU).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It certainly wouldn't be "around 1700", since apparently [in **1769** the celebrated Scottish traveller James Bruce first sent a description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensete_ventricosum#History) back to England (of a tree common in ... Abyssinia).

I suspect OP's 1837 reference is actually [this OCR error](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22they%20are%20false%20banana%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). The earliest I can find is [the mid 1890s](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22they%20are%20false%20banana%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22banana%20ark%20false%22&tbm=bks) where several different "country names" are listed for...

[The Asimina Triloba](http://www.treesofnorthamerica.net/trees/Fetid-shrub) is commonly known as Custard Apple, Dog Banana, **False-banana**, Fetid-shrub, Indian Banana, Pawpaw, as well as Pawpaw-apple.

To save anyone the trouble of squinting to make out what it says in those 1890s links, it was apparently being called "false banana" in ***Illinois*** back then. But there's scope for confusion, because ***false xxxx*** is a common "popular name" format for plants<sup>1</sup>, and I've no way of knowing whether OP is specifically interested in [**Asimina triloba** or **Ensete ventricosum**](http://www.jungleseeds.co.uk/contents/en-uk/d119_Top_Selling_Flower_Seeds.html). I'm guessing the first, since it's an economically important *food* plant, whereas the second is a decorative shrub, but obviously the name is/has been applied to both.

<sup>1</sup> Oregon State University [Common Names for Landscape Plants](http://oregonstate.edu/dept/ldplants/common.htm) includes 15 ***false xxxx*** entries.

Comment: Custard apple sounds more fun than the fetid-shrub!

Comment: So does Ensete ventricosum!

Answer (score 8):

The first occurrence in Google Books of "false banana" is in a U.S. Department of Agriculture bulletin by George Sudworth, "Nomenclature of the Arborescent Flora of the United States" (1897). [My thanks to Hugo for pointing out my error in supposing that the reference to "false banana" was in an earlier bulletin, called "Some Foreign Trees for the Southern States" (1895), in the same Google Books bundle.] In Sudworth's bulletin, the common name "false banana" is associated with a plant whose Latin (genus and species) name is Asimina triloba; the more common name for the plant at that time was "papaw" (now "pawpaw"), but it was also known as "custard apple" (in several North American localities), "banana" (in Arkansas), "jasmine" or "jasminier" (in parts of Louisiana), "fetid shrub" (in parts of North Carolina), and "false banana" (in parts of Illinois).

The plant commonly known as "false banana" today is the Ensete ventricosum (also commonly known as "Ethiopian banana," "Abyssinian banana," and "ensete"). According to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensete_ventricosum) about it, the false banana's fruit is inedible, but its root is a staple food in the diets of some people who live in southern Ethiopia.

As for the history of the noun, it is simply a compound of "false" and a familiar plant that it isn't. The *Some Foreign Trees* book lists several similar common names: "false acacia," "false boxwood," "false box dogwood," false mahogany," and "false maple."

Your 1837 first occurrence date coincides with an erroneous "match" for "false banana" in Google Books—which is actually a citation of this quotation by Albert Barnes, appearing in a snippet view of text from William Jenks, *Acts-Revelation* (1838):

> If they are in accordance with the first triumphs of the Gospel, they are genuine; if not, they are false.   BARNES

Barnes published his *Notes on the Bible* in 1834, but he did not (to my knowledge) discuss false bananas.

Comment: I couldn't make out "Barnes" from the scanned copy I was looking at, but I was pretty certain "Bananas" was an OCR error. Anyway, +1 for that bit of scrupulous research!

Comment: Do you have a link for *Some Foreign Trees for the Southern States* (1896)? I found [two](http://archive.org/details/someforeigntree00ferngoog) [1895](http://archive.org/details/someforeigntrees11fern) copies, neither of which seems to mention it.

Comment: Hi, Hugo. I typed the wrong date—my reference (from an Ngram Viewer search) was published in 1895, too. I've corrected the typo. Here is the URL for the "False Banana" occurrence: http://books.google.com/books?id=-4U5AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA200&dq=%22false+banana%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cjw3UszFO63biwLq2oE4&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22false%20banana%22&f=false

Comment: Thank you kindly, FumbleFingers. I couldn't read "Barnes" either, so I ran a search on the quotation itself to track down its author. I always like it when someone characterizes that kind of behavior as "scrupulous," rather than "obsessive." When I saw that your answer had so much in common with mine, I almost pulled mine—but there were enough minor differences to stay my hand.

Comment: Yeah - there's nothing wrong with two "similar, but independently-researched" answers. On giving it a bit more thought, it seems to me the frequency of ***false xxxx*** in "common" plant names is significant here. We'd both made that point anyway, but I've added a link in mine to show just *how* "common" (sorry! :) it is.

Comment: @SvenYargs: I think the 1895 is misdated. The snippet says it's on page 200 and the text matches that found on page 200 of the 1897 in my answer. There's lots of bad metadata in Google Books and sometimes several books run together, so you have to be especially wary with snippets. (Anyway, two years isn't much.)

Comment: You're right, Hugo. I was deceived by the similar subjects into thinking that the bulletin (from 1895) named in the Google Books search results was the same one you identified (and dated) correctly as Sudworth's "Nomenclature..." (1897). In fact the "Some Foreign Trees" bulletin is rather short and is separated from the "Nomenclature" bulletin by yet another bulletin in the same Google Books bundle—this one on the subject of "Timber Trestle Bridges." I see now that I need to be careful about instances of Google Books bundling.

Comment: "If they are in accordance with the first triumphs of the Gospel, they are genuine; if not, they are false bananas."

Answer (score 5):

### *Banana*

The first quotation for plain *banana* in the OED is by William Dampier in *A new voyage round the world* (1697):

> The *Bonano* Tree is exactly like the Plantain.

The etymology:

> Portuguese *banana* or Spanish *banana* (the fruit), Portuguese *banano* or Spanish *banano* (the tree), given by De Orta (1563) and Pigafetta, as the name used in Guinea (Congo).

### *False banana*

The earliest verifiable example I can find of *false banana* is as the common name used in Illinois for *Asimina triloba*, in *[Nomenclature of the arborescent flora of the United States](http://archive.org/details/nomenclatureofar14sudw)* (21 January 1897, [read online](http://archive.org/stream/nomenclatureofar14sudw#page/200/mode/1up)) by dendrologist George B. Sudworth and published by the U.S. Dept. of Agriculture, Forestry Division:

> [image: False Banana (Ill.).]
>
> Syn.— Papaw (R. I.,Del.,K Y., N. J., D. C., Ya.,W. Ya.,N. C.,S. 0.,
> Ga., Miss., La., Ky.,Ohio, 111., Ind., Mo., Iowa, Kans., Nebr.).
> Custard Apple (Ont., Del., Pa., Ohio, S. C, Miss.).
> Banana (Ark.).
> False Banana (Ill.).
> Jasmine (La.).
> Jasminier (La.).
> Fetid Shrub (N. C.).